# C# XNA Render Target

Tags: c#, xna

I've been trying to read pixels from screen, someone told me about the code "Render Target", anyone knows how this works?? (I googled for some minutes but can't find any code that works )
Thx

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think the point is to render onto a texture, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The `Texture2D` class contains [`GetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.getdata.aspx) and [`SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx) methods.

Comment: And `RenderTarget2D` is a `Texture2D`.